# Compensation pulse for plateau through bias-tee

Tags: pulse, bias

I'm sending a series of square pulses through the RF side of an homemade bias-tee (R = 1e6 Ohm, C=0.1uF).
Unfortunately, my experiment requires that some of those pulses have plateau time longer than the time constant. I'm thinking of sending a compensated function at the input so the output effectively sees a plateau, but I don't really know where to start. Any tips?

Some precisions :
Because I want to be able to sweep the DC side at a certain ramp rate I can't just increase C as it would increase the time constant.

Also, I'm working at 10 mK temperature which limits the component I can use.

Comment: Make a longer time constant then?

Comment: In very general terms, you have an input driving function, a system response to it, and a transfer function that explains the response. If you know the transfer function and the desired response, you can work backwards (inverse Fourier) to figure out the required driving function. Same thing is done when masking IC wafers at tiny scales. They know the required mask on the wafer (design) and they study thoroughly how the lithography system 'convolutes things' along the way, which tells them how to drive the lithography to get the desired mask. (Involves division so it is noisy.)

Comment: Look up the term 'deconvolution.'

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with analyzing complex bias-tees. You'll need to work out the transfer function it represents to your input (how it convolves the input.) But with it, you can work out the input drive given a desired output (and assuming it is possible at all.) For example, I've taken a pulse, convolved it with gauss filter, to get the resulting output. Then I took the output (assuming it is desired) and deconvolved it with the gauss filter. Note that [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ntJb.png) matches the original drive. This is what I mean. But your bias-tee is key, right now.